# Is there a Count function within the aggregate Window functions in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, count, aggregate, window-functions

I´m trying to count the number of rows within a window and having that value in a column for each window.
To do that, I´m just using the row_number function, and then getting the max number of that row_number column.
My question is: Is there a more effective way to achieve this goal, avoiding these two steps? Does the windos functions have a count function?

Here´s my code:

```
output_df = input_df\
    .withColumn('row_number_window', row_number().over(window))\
    .withColumn('n_rows_count', max('row_number_window').over(window))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
count(lit(1)).over(window)
```